# Saga not fired by action Redux-Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, saga

Why will not my saga be fired by my action? I have a wierd situation where it works when I do this: open my application in the browser (and use npm run start to start the application), exit the run of application, and then start the application with npm run start (whith the previous display of the application in the browser)

I know that the action are fired, but my saga is not. However, when I do as i described, it works, and the saga gets fired by the same action (as it should in the first place)

I have tried to connect the saga and reducer in several ways: direct in the component that uses it, and on the «top layer», where all components can reach them.

And by the way: it seems like the ropt saga are connected both with and without the wierd «fix», since it console.log’s out my console.log

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please include code of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I had a saga above the saga that never got fired. The reason for why my saga never fired as expected was because of the saga above where an error happened.